# Can't update or uninstall iTunes for Windows

Tags: itunes, windows

Whenever I try to uninstall or update iTunes on my Windows computer, it just says:

```
The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable.

Click OK to try again, or enter an alternate path to a folder containing the installation package 'iTunes64.msi' in the box below.
```

I searched everywhere for an `iTunes 64.msi` file, and can not find it. I already tried repairing it several times and did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following link to download iTunes for Windows (64-bit):

- https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/win64

For 32-bit version, use this link instead:

- https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/win32

Alternatively, iTunes for Windows can also be installed from the Microsoft Store by opening the following link on your computer running Microsoft Windows:

- https://www.microsoft.com/p/itunes/9pb2mz1zmb1s

Comment: it doesn't work. I get an error message saying "an older version of iTunes could not be removed"
or something like that